# How to retrieve images (decoded if possible) present in a wepage using XPCOM

Tags: image, firefox, xpcom

How to get all the images, after decoding if possible, on a webpage through XPCOM ?

The image might be specified in HTML as a background url in some CSS property, inside img tag, or in any form that a web developer might have included.

I tried looking into imgIContainer, imgIDecodeObserver and many other interfaces. Although there is a way through which we can provide image URI to Mozilla so that it loads the image, decodes it and returns imgIContainer. But I couldn't find anyway to get all images in current webpage.

This has to be done in either Java or Javascript.

Any suggestions?

---

@Wladimir - Thanks for your help.

I want all the images including CSS constructs (background images). So now I am listening to events from nsIWebProgressListener.

```
    onStateChange: function(webProgress, request, stateFlags, status) {
        if ((~stateFlags & (nsIWebProgressListener.STATE_IS_REQUEST | nsIWebProgressListener.STATE_STOP)) == 0) {
            var imgReq = request.QueryInterface(CI.imgIRequest);
            if (imgReq)
                var img = imgReq.image;
        }
    }
```

The problem is that `request.QueryInterface(CI.imgIRequest)` throws exception for all NON-image requests. Although those exceptions can be ignored by putting code inside try-catch block, but I'd prefer to do things cleanly.

Is there any condition that can be checked to know whether request is for image or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is existing code that you can look at. The Page Info dialog has a Media tab that successfully shows most images on the page. The important function is [`grabAll()` in `pageInfo.js`](http://hg.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/file/b5765cc9da6c/browser/base/content/pageinfo/pageInfo.js#l667), it is called for each element (via a [TreeWalker](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.createTreeWalker)). As you can see, there is no generic way to get the image, this function rather uses [`window.getComputedStyle()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.getComputedStyle) to extract the values of a bunch of the CSS properties for this element: `background-image`, `border-image`, `list-style-image`, `cursor`. It will also look for `<img>`, `<svg:image>`, `<link>` (favicon), `<input>`, `<button>`, `<object>` and `<embed>` tags. It doesn't manage to recognize everything however, e.g. these CSS constructs will not be recognized:

```css
.foo:before
{
  content: url(image.png);
}
.foo:hover
{
  background-image: url(image.png);
}
```

Still, this is probably as far as you can get - unless you want to look at the requests made by the web page as it loads.

**Edit**: If you look at the requests as they are performed (via a [web progress listener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Code_snippets/Progress_Listeners)), you can do the following:

```js
if (request instanceof CI.imgIRequest)
  var img = request.URI.spec;
```

Note that `request.image` won't help you much, almost all methods of `imgIContainer` are only accessible from native code.

Comment: As I said: "unless you want to look at the requests made by the web page as it loads". However, your question sounded like you wanted to extract images from a page that already loaded.

Comment: Yes, thats what I wanted. For some reason, I am not able to put my code here with proper formatting. Let me try few more tricks to put my code here.

Comment: @Ankur: Please add your own answer and accept it. The "help" link explains how to format code.

Comment: thanks again for your help. I'll try this and let you know the result. Thanks a lot !!

Comment: Thanks a alot. I was able to get imgIContainer objects successfully by observing imgIRequest.